# Kotlin Extensions - Synthetic imports show compilation error in child class

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I have a class A where my view fragment_my_quests is defined. Synthetic imports works fine in class A.
Now I extend B with A and try to use Synthetic import and id's inside my child class B.
It shows red (compilation error). But when I run the app, it works fine. 
Just the compiler is not able to understand this. I am attaching  screenshots for the reference.

Koltlin version : 1.3.20
Anko version : 0.10.8
Gradle version : 3.3.0

*This is the screenshot for parent class. Synthetic imports works fine and do not show any compilation error.*
[image]

*This is the screenshot for child class. Synthetic imports and the id's used in child class shows red.*

[image]

Comment: try importing `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_my_quests.view.*`

Comment: Hi, maybe trying restarting android studio invalidating its caches and then resyncking the project with the gradle files again would remove the error?

Comment: Have tried restarting, invalidating cache, deleting gradle, rebuilding. Doesn't work

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-22430, it's still an issue. You may use ButterKnife extension to overcome Synthetic Imports Error.

Answer (score 0):

Try as follows

- Menu > File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Build -> Clean Project
- Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files

If not work then delete the ./gradle directory and import your project again
try above 3 steps.